# Jquery Star Rating and Infinite Scroll, how to initialize after dom is loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using this jquery star rating plugin : http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/
And an infinite scroll plugin to load my posts.
When the second page of posts is automaticly loaded the star rating plugin breaks down and shows just input buttons. I also had this problem with the facebook and twitter share buttons, but i managed to fix that with the following code:

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
try{
    FB.XFBML.parse(); 
    twttr.widgets.load();
}catch(ex){}
});
            </script>
```

Since i dont have any knowledge about jquery or javascript, i really dont have a clue on how to initialize the plugin again after new content is loaded. Could someone please help me out on this?

Thanks!

edit :

This infinite scroll plugin : http://www.fieg.nl/infinite-ajax-scroll-a-jquery-plugin

Comment: An infinite scroll plugin? *Which* infinite scroll plugin? Check the api for a `loaded` hook, and bind your initialisations to that.

Comment: As i said i dont have any knowledge about jquery or javascript so what you are saying sounds like a mystery to me :P

Comment: That library has an [onRenderComplete](https://github.com/webcreate/Infinite-Ajax-Scroll#onrendercomplete) callback, give that a go and see what you can come up with.

Comment: i have tried to add this : onLoadItems: function(items) {
            
          $('.auto-submit-star').rating('enable');   
            
        } however this also doesn't work :( any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Ive managed to fix it, with the OnRendercomplete as Christian Varga Suggested, here is the code if someone else runs into this problem :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.ias({
    container: '.listing',
    item: '.box',
    pagination: '.pagination',
    next: '.next a',
    loader: '<img src="images/loader.gif"/>',
    onRenderComplete: function (items) {

        FB.XFBML.parse();
        twttr.widgets.load();

        $(function () {
            $('.auto-submit-star').rating({
                callback: function (value, link) {

                    //   this.form.submit();
                    $('.auto-submit-star').rating('readOnly', true)
                    $(this.form).ajaxSubmit();


                    return false;



                }
            });
        });

    }
});
```